# Input Type Number, no negative sign or decimals allowed?

Tags: android, textinput

I have two edittext views that I using for a calculation and both need to be limited to numbers only so I'm using the InputType to do this, but now I cannot enter a negative number or any numbers containing decimals!

Any ideas or solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You should use `numberSigned` or `numberDecimal`, or both `numberDecimal|numberSigned` to enable features you need.

Comment: Isn't it the opposite to what the questions asks?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the below and even the device input keyboard will contain numbers only:

```
myTextView.setInputType(
  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```